# Error when sending an alert reminder for an email using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send a reminder alert along with an email from an application using C# code but I am getting an error: "An invalid character was found in header name." at this line email.Headers.Add("Follow up by:", string.Format("{0: dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zz}", ReplyDate)); below is my code:

```
        public bool SendEmail(EmailInformation emailInformation, ProcessInformation processInformation)
    {
        try
        {
            string emailBody = GenerateEmail(emailInformation, processInformation);

            if (processInformation.Success)
            {
                string emailSubject = _settings.DefaultEmailSubject;

                EmailEngine engine = new EmailEngine(_settings);
                engine.Send(emailInformation.RecipientEmailAddress, emailBody, emailSubject); <-- this method is showing below

                DateTime emailSent = DateTime.Now;

                UpdateEmailSentInformation(emailInformation.CompanyId, emailInformation.SupervisorId, emailSent, processInformation);

                if (processInformation.Success)
                {
                    ArchiveEmail(emailInformation, emailBody, processInformation);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            processInformation.AddContent("Exception encountered " + ex.Message);
            processInformation.Success = false;
        }

        return processInformation.Success;
    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public void Send(string recipientEmail, string emailBody, string emailSubject)
    {
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(_settings.EmailServer);

        DateTime ReplyDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
        //email.Headers.Add("X-Message-Flag", "Follow up");
        email.Headers.Add("Follow up by:", string.Format("{0: dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zz}", ReplyDate)); <-- here is where the error is throwing 

        email.From = new MailAddress(_settings.SenderEmail);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_settings.TestingEmail))
        {
           email.To.Add(_settings.TestingEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            email.To.Add(recipientEmail);
        }

        email.Subject = emailSubject;

        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        email.Body = emailBody;

        smtpServer.Send(email);
    }
}
```

I also tried this

```
email.Headers.Add("Follow up by:", string.Format("{0:g}", ReplyDate));
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Altrough this header is not known to me, in general deaders do not contsin spaces, but dashes instead. Try `Follow-up-by`. And I think colon will be added automatically, you dont need to add yourself. That can be also the cause of this exception. Or both.

Comment: If it work without your special header?

Comment: @ZorgoZ Thank you that fixed the issue but I don't see any reminder alert on the email that was sent. any idea how would I make this work?

Comment: I dont think this is a standard header. It migjt depend on your mail system. Are you sure this is valid? Have you seen a working example?

Comment: @ZorgoZ I am using MailMessage email = new MailMessage(); and after searching I came across this post to use the header. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/466d3413-4d3a-4898-9665-da8e7e4b4593/sending-email-marked-as-followup-through-c-code?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I dont see your header anywhere in that post, only `Reply-By`.

Comment: @ZorgoZ thank you very much, some one suggested the below code and it worked: mailMessage.Headers["X-Message-Flag"] = "Follow up";
mailMessage.Headers["Reply-By"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss %K");

Comment: @ZorgoZ I think I spoke too early on this :(, the Follow Up by <Date> is coming on the header of the email but the reminder popup is not coming. would you happen to know why?

Comment: @N.Barcham First of all: what client are you trying to work with? Not all support such headers. `X-Message-Flag` is almost Microsoft-only (Exchange + Outlook) feature (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2156.html) - it is not widely supported. Beware that the `%K` does not comply to the RFC822 date-time format (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html)! Better try using GMT/UTC date.

Comment: `var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");


var replyBy = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToString(@"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \G\M\T", culture);`

Comment: @ZorgoZ I am working with Microsoft Outlook the above helped in resolving the date issue but I am still having issues with the pop up reminder it is not coming up for the time showing on the header.

Comment: And what is your server? Because if it is Exchange, you have better options.

Comment: @ZorgoZ yes it is Microsoft Exchange 365 outlook account, but I keep searching for a solution and I can't find anything to make it work.

Comment: @N.Barcham, ok so you want to reproduce this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-an-email-message-with-a-follow-up-reminder-740a3b9e-e837-4711-938a-08dd0ea5ac64. If you are using thick Outlook client and Office365 and it works, then it is supported by EWS. The ReminderDueBy property is valid for Message class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/reminderdueby), thus you certainly can create emails with managed api. I recommend sincerely `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard` library for you.